# R programming - Computational time taken for comparing strings vs comparing integers?

Tags: r, time

I would like to know if string comparison is faster or slower than integer comparison for similar size (ex. 3 character string vs 3 digit number). Or is speed irrelevant to data type?
I'm asking this question because even a little difference would matter when I have to process millions of user's data.

Comment: Why don't you try it?  Use `library(microbenchmark)` and/or `system.time` and/or `Rprof`

Comment: Are these comparisons really the slow part of your code?  You may be suffering from premature optimization. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears string comparison is slower.

```
x <- 1:11+100; y <- 11:1+100; cx <- as.character(x); cy <- as.character(y)
library(microbenchmark) # In line with Richard Scriven's comment
microbenchmark(x == y, cx == cy, times = 1000000)
# Unit: nanoseconds
#      expr min  lq median  uq       max neval
#    x == y 318 408    477 664 108641192 1e+06
#  cx == cy 521 633    701 943 111547387 1e+06
```

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but why are `x` and `y` such short vectors?

Comment: I can confirm the benchmark, even with much longer arrays, although the ~1.4 times difference in median times for 100 elements becomes a ~3.1 times difference for 100k elements.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
  start.time<-Sys.time()    
  [your propgraming code]    
  end.time<-Sys.time()   
  s<-end.time-start.time  
  s
```

you will get your answer. Apply this on both string and numerical digit. you can identify the computational time of both string and numeric digit.